# How to create a Toolbar with Mail / Finder like controls

Tags: macos, cocoa, interface-builder, appkit

I've been looking at this apple document:

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AppleHIGuidelines/Controls/Controls.html

In the `Window-Frame Controls` section it deescribes

> window-frame controls in the Mail toolbar

[image: Mail Toolbar]
<sub>(source: [apple.com](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AppleHIGuidelines/art/ct_toolbarcontrols.jpg))</sub>

However, there's no description on how to actually create this interface. I've tried using `NSToolBar` but it doesn't seem to be used for this purpose and there doesn't seem to be a way to drag a `NSButton` into this area in InterfaceBuilder.

Any pointers on how to create this type of toolbar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drag object Toolbar from Object Library to you window. Double click on toolbar. Drag button from the Object library into the Allowed Toolbar Item section. 1-click on button in toolbar manage attributes toolbar item section, double click manage button attributes. Connect action with your new toolbar item.

Comment: The allowed items section is such a non-standard UI element I didn't even think of that. Thanks.